# How to import data using PowerBi RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to import data from PowerBi App to Excel Power Pivot using RLS. Unfortunately, although I've made roles and assigned them to different people, it doesn't work when importing data to excel from PowerBi. I've checked the correctness of the roles and they work perfectly on a server, but I can't import them by roles. Please, any advice? .

Comment: Can you clarify "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft people with assigned roles see whole Power Pivot, with all the data

Comment: What roles do they have.  If it's anything other than Workspace Viewer, this is by design.